# Samsung Series 5 display brightness keys not working after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a Samsung NP530U3C-A0AUK that came with Windows 8. I recently upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10, and since then, the screen brightness adjust function keys (<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>) have stopped working.

The volume adjust function keys (<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>/<kbd>F7</kbd>/<kbd>F8</kbd>) and touchpad disable key (<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>) do still work.

I've tried updating the following drivers: Intel HD Graphics 4000 display adapter (didn't solve the problem), Generic PnP Monitor and Standard PS/2 Keyboard (both already up to date). There isn't a keyboard driver on the Samsung support website.

Is there a registry setting that can be changed to re-enable the brightness keys?

To clarify: I can fully adjust the screen brightness in Settings

Another problem I am having post-Win10: [Samsung Series 5 does not automatically wake up from sleep on lid open after Win 10 upgrade](https://superuser.com/questions/1083618/samsung-series-5-does-not-automatically-wake-up-from-sleep-on-lid-open-after-win)

Comment: This and your other question both sound like you're missing some driver that enables extra BIOS features in Windows. I don't know about Samsung, but eg. Asus has one on all its laptops and when it's missing or malfunctioning `Fn` key behaves erroneously and laptops have various sleep and hibernation issues.

Comment: @gronostaj Any idea which driver? I can't seem to find a suitable one on the [Samsung website for this laptop](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/NP530U3C-A0AUK), and they're all old drivers anyway (Windows 7 - so old even for when the laptop shipped)

Comment: I have looked there too, but didn't find anything that looks like what you need. Maybe Windows Update will be able to find it? It usually handles drivers quite well, I'd give it a try. Just install all available updates.[SWUpdate](http://orcaservice.samsungmobile.com/SWUpdate.aspx) may work too.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely one of the driver packages distributed via the SWUpdate program. Install the SWUpdate program and let it install all available drivers and this and the resume problem will be sorted.

Comment: This is a good answer but if you include the download link and add a few images and steps, this answer would be a whole lot better.

Comment: I tried this, and although I was able to download the more stable Windows 8.1 touchpad driver, I couldn't find a suitable driver to rectify the brightness keys or lid problem